# A Twitter application with only two users

Tags: twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I'm making a Twitter application that makes one Twitter account echo another.

I used the http://dev.twitter.com tool to obtain the access token associate with one account, but since only one person can administer a Twitter application I can't get an access token for any other accounts.

It would appear I have to build an entire 3-legged-oauth strategy only to get one access token!

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens

How can I most easily acquire an access token for the other user? I don't need a strategy to get many of them, just one.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found the answer after a few hours of searching.

You can do it fastest using the PIN auth method and you'll never have to do it again.

Additionally, this gist contains some awesome Ruby code so I didn't have to do any coding, and I got my access token right from the command line:

https://gist.github.com/mirakui/388067

Cheers.